# Polygon Onclick Openwindow

Tags: android, polygon

I want make application on `Android` with multiple `polygon`, and when i click one polygon it show something like open window and show detail of the `polygon`. Is there any solution to make function like that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use ImageButtons for polygon images and handle their click events by opening new activity or dialog for showing information about the polygons.

You will handle the click events like this:

```
ImageButton ib = findViewById(R.id.polygon1);
ib.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //show dialog or new activity with details
        Intent i=new Intent();
        int polygon_id = id_of_polygon;
        i.putExtra("id", polygon_id);
        i.startActivity(this,DetailsActivity.class);
        finish(); 
    }
});
```

You can get this value in details activity like this:

```
       int id;
       if (savedInstanceState == null) {
         Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
         if(extras == null) {
           id= 0;
         } else {
         id= extras.getInt("id");
         }
      }
```

Then in this activity you can show details about the polygon.

All this code will be added to the onCreate() methods of the activities.